# Notification icon seen all time at the title bar?

Tags: android, notifications, titlebar

I am doing an app and i am using notification.When i run my code i can see notification icon at the titlebar it is ok and when i swipe at the down and click it it is also open up huhu class.My question is icon is always seen at the title bar.Click the info window i want to icon gone.How can i do that?

My code:

```
    Intent openintent = new Intent(context,huhu.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                    nm = (NotificationManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                          CharSequence from = "Did you miss "+loglist.get(i).contactname+" ?";
                          CharSequence message = "You didnt call "+loglist.get(i).contactname+" Today";
                          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                                  openintent, 0);
                          Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                            "Daily Call Reminder! ", System.currentTimeMillis());
                          notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
                          nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Answer (score 0):

after

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                        "Daily Call Reminder! ", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

put

```
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```